# How to find a convex function such that $F$ is $C^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation

Given the function $F(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\leq 1; \\
      f(x) & 1\leq x\leq 3; \\
      2x^2 & 3\leq x.\end{cases}$

I would like to know if there is a general method to find $f$ convex such that $F$ is $C^2$. I directly tried to interpolate with $f$ a polynomial of degree 5 such that $f(1)=1,f'(1)=f''(1)=0$ and $f(3)=18,f'(3)=12,f''(3)=4$. The problem is that $f''(x)\not\geq 0,\forall 1\leq x\leq 3$.

Comment: What happens when you try a $6$th degree polynomial?  Does that give you enough "slack" to solve the problem?

Comment: What should be the conditions that I would need to impose to find such polynomial?

Comment: You have the right conditions.  The polynomial will be underdetermined, so that should help.

Comment: @RobertShore Curiously, even a 6th-degree polynomial interpolation doesn't exist.  I did manage to find a 7th-degree polynomial - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 7th-degree polynomial
$$ \begin{split}
\phi(x)
&= \frac{2}{5} x^7
- \frac{13}{2} x^6
+ \frac{3551}{80} x^5
- \frac{6547}{40} x^4 \\
&\quad + \frac{13899}{40} x^3
- \frac{8303}{20} x^2
+ \frac{20547}{80} x
- \frac{2511}{40}
\end{split} $$
should do the job.

Here is a plot of the $C^2$ function $F$:

[image: plot of F]

and its continuous nonnegative second derivative $F''$:

[image: plot of the second derivative of F]

---

Curiously, there is no 6th-degree polynomial interpolation satisfying the given constraints as suggested by [Robert Shore](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/640080)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4606046#comment9705268_4606046).

Suppose that we try a 6th-degree polynomial
$$
\phi(x) = a x^6 + b x^5 + c x^4 + d x^3 + e x^2 + f x + g.
$$
The constraints
\begin{align*}
\phi(1) &= 1, \\
\phi'(1) &= 0, \\
\phi''(1) &= 0, \\
\phi(3) &= 18, \\
\phi'(3) &= 12, \\
\phi''(3) &= 4
\end{align*}
translate to
\begin{align*}
 a+b+c+d+e+f+g&=1 \\
 6 a+5 b+4 c+3 d+2 e+f&=0, \\
 30 a+20 b+12 c+6 d+2 e&=0, \\
 729 a+243 b+81 c+27 d+9 e+3 f+g&=18, \\
 1458 a+405 b+108 c+27 d+6 e+f&=12, \\
 2430 a+540 b+108 c+18 d+2 e&=4,
\end{align*}
whose solution is
\begin{align*}
 b &= \frac{1}{16} (19-192 a), \\
 c &= \frac{3}{8} (152 a-33), \\
 d &= \frac{1}{8} (383-1088 a), \\
 e &= \frac{1}{4} (684 a-325), \\
 f &= \frac{27}{16} (37 - 64 a), \\
 g &= \frac{27}{8} (8 a-5). \\
\end{align*}
Additionally, we need to satisfy the convexity constraint
$$
\phi''(x) > 0 \qquad \text{ for all } 1 < x < 3,
$$
where
$$ \begin{split}
\phi''(x) &= 30 a x^4+20 b x^3+12 c x^2+6 d x+2 e \\
&= 30 a x^4+\frac{5}{4} (19-192 a) x^3 \\
&\quad +\frac{9}{2}
   (152 a-33) x^2 + \frac{3}{4} (383-1088 a)
   x+\frac{1}{2} (684 a-325).
\end{split} $$
This is where things go awry.  By inspecting the two particular points
$$
\phi'' \biggl( \frac{10}{9} \biggr) = -\frac{2 (4063 a-6465)}{2187}
$$
and
$$
\phi'' \biggl( \frac{22}{9} \biggr) = \frac{13 (10 a-129)}{2187},
$$
we see that we need both
$$
a < \frac{6465}{4063} < 2
$$
and
$$
a > \frac{129}{10} > 12,
$$
which is not possible.

---

Fortunately, a similar process and some trial and error successfully found the 7th-degree polynomial listed at the top of this answer.